# Will beacon of hope work on Channel Divinity: Preserve life?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, healing

I am a 6th-level [Life-domain cleric](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/cleric#LifeDomain). I have 1 hp left in the pool of 30  HP from the Channel Divinity: Preserve Life feature:

> Starting at 2nd level, you can use your Channel Divinity to heal the badly injured.
>
> As an action, you present your holy symbol and evoke healing energy that can restore a number of hit points equal to five times your cleric level. Choose any creatures within 30 feet of you, and divide those hit points among them. This feature can restore a creature to no more than half of its hit point maximum. You can’t use this feature on an undead or a construct.

I use the 3rd-level spell *[Beacon of Hope](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/beacon-of-hope)* which allows maximum healing on anything:

> For the duration, each target [...] regains the maximum number of hit points possible from any healing.

Will giving 1 HP worth (of this pool of 30 HP) to someone heal them 30 HP (the maximum for that pool)?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. Tags tell readers what game *and* edition the question's about to facilitate easier filtering. (Don't worry about this question; I fixed the tags for you.) Thank you for participating and have fun.

Comment: Hi, I've clarified the wording in the hopes of making it clearer and getting the question reopened. If I have in any way misrepresented your question, let me know and/or revert it to the previous version of your question via the rollback button within [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/125212/revisions).

Comment: @Apocalisp See [this FAQ](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/321) for why your comment was removed. Thanks!

Comment: If this had worked, it would be massively broken.

Answer (score 8):

## No, this will not work

From *[beacon of life](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/beacon-of-hope)*, PHB pg. 217:

> Choose any number of creatures within range. For the duration, each target has advantage on Wisdom saving throws and death saving throws, and regains the **maximum number of hit points possible from any healing**.

This allows the maximum amount of healing from spells or features that use a die to give a random number of hit die, such as Cure Wounds that uses a d8.

From [Channel Divinity: Preserve Life](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/cleric#LifeDomain), PHB pg. 60:

> As an action, you present your holy symbol and **evoke healing energy** that can restore **a number of hit points equal to five times your cleric level**. Choose any creatures within 30 feet of you, and **divide those hit points among them**.

This creates a static 30 hit points (if you are a level 6 cleric), rather than a randomly determined number of hit points, the maximum of which is 30. You then distribute these hit points over multiple creatures. In other words, the point at which *[beacon of life](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/beacon-of-hope)* would have been applied would have been when the 30 hit points were "evoked", not during the distribution of them.

Unforunately, your plan of combining these two effects to give 30 HP to everyone will not work.